# Android Datepicker dialog is having transparent background

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using datepickerdialog in dialogfragement and the spinners are transparent as showing in this image[image: Transparent Spinners]
How i can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: check your theme that you have applied to this

Comment: paste your styles.xml code.

Comment: Did  you check in real device other than an emulator ?

Answer (score 2):

Define a custom dialog theme by setting the back ground color in your styles.xml as below.

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

And apply this theme to the date picker dialog while creating as

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme,
                new MyDateSetListener(), selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDate);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be happening only with visual studio android emulator. When i try to run it in the native android emulator the problem is not happening. And also on real devices everything seems to be okey. Any one have an idea why the visual studio android emulator behaves differently?

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme,
            new MyDateSetListener(), selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDate);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.color.white));
```

I faced same problem and this did the job done